# Nested selectors using Sass

Tags: css, sass

How can I have this output using Sass?

```
.class.active  .class-name1 {}
.class.active  .class-name2 {}
```

Here is what I tried :

```
.class {
    &.avtive {
        &-name1 {

        }

        &-name2 {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to the outer class name, and interpolate it for your `-name` classes. Using `color: red` as an example of the style to apply:

```
.class {
    $outer-class: &;
    &.active {
        #{$outer-class}-name1 {
          color: red;
        }

        #{$outer-class}-name2 {
          color: red;
        }
    }
}
```